# Can I create a program in Clojure able to edit it's own code?

Tags: clojure

I am thinking of creating an educational program in Clojure that would show a console where the user could edit code in order to change a running code in another part of the screen (like a game, for instance). Would that be possible? If so, what should I study in order to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. See this [Interactive programming Flappy Bird in ClojureScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZjFVdU8VLI)  . It uses clojurescript and [figwheel](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel) as its development environment.

The awesome thing about figwheel is that you can change the flappybird running code in the browser by simply evaluating new code in the repl and then figwheel push the new code to the browser. The changes happened in real time.

You can start studying clojure and clojurescript.

Comment: This is more in line with what I'm looking for. Is something similar to this available for Clojure instead of ClojureScript?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, this presentation in clojurewest just 4 days ago is more in line with what you're looking for. 'Zach Oakes - Making Games at Runtime with Clojure' ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GzzFeS5cMc )

Answer (score 0):

Hm, changing code during runtime is one of the basic concepts behind clojure. 
Watch this for more on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P76Vbsk_3J0

Otherwise every repl or form of a repl can do that.
To get started have a look at Lighttable: http://lighttable.com/ It has inline evaluation in the editor.